# Run a specific task when the task required by user is not present in the gulpfile

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Is there any way to run a specific task when the task supplied by the user is not present in the `gulpfile`.

For example, if the user runs `gulp build` and the `build` task is not there in the `gulpfile` then a specific task (or default task, doesn't matter to me) should run.

As an analogy, consider the specified task as the **404 page** for `gulp`.

Comment: You could run `gulp build || gulp` to invoke `default` if `build` fails or doesn't exist.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am not going to run those tasks, other developers will and I want to show them a meaningful message on what to do when the task is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gulp`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/index.js#L9-L12) inherits from [`orchestrator`](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator/blob/master/index.js#L10-L16), which contains a `tasks` instance variable that is a plain object with keys that are names of tasks added to the instance. If you replaced `tasks` with a [`proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get), you could have it return a default task, like `default` by using the `get` trap handler:

```
const gulp = require('gulp')

gulp.tasks = new Proxy(gulp.tasks, {
  get (target, property) {
    if (target.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      return target[property]
    }

    return target.default
  }
})
```

That code can be run at anytime before the sequence of tasks is started, even after some tasks have already been added to the `gulp` instance.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's answer was really helpful. I had to modify a little since I was getting an ESLint warning and the following error -

```
TypeError: this.tasks.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

So I thought to post my changes too. Here's my final code -

```
gulp.tasks = new Proxy(gulp.tasks, {
    get: function(target, property) {
        if (undefined !== target[property]) {
            return target[property];
        }
        return target.default; //or target["<Custom task name>"]
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting [`yoda` error](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/yoda) for the ordering of `undefined !== target[property]`

Comment: I use this way so that I don't accidentally assign undefined to the variables. I think undefined check is protected from yoda ;-)